# checks for conditions dynamically if blank replaces with null

Tags: c#

C#

```
    Class x
    {
    string Insurer{get;set;}
    }
Now,

x.Insurer=txtInsurer.Text;
```

now File strText Contains @Insurer replace with x.Insurer

```
strText = strText.Replace("@Insurer","\""+x.Insuerer+"\"");
```

output of strText is

Insurer:"",

my Requirement is if txtInsurer.Text is empty then strText File contains @Insurer `replaces with null i.e Insurer:null,`

```
instead of Insurer:"",
```

Comment: hard to understand

Comment: would be better if you could provide example data and expected result

Comment: not able to understand what you want exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *ternary* operator:

```
strText = strText.Replace("@Insurer", x.Insuerer == null 
  ? "NULL" 
  : ("\"" + x.Insuerer + "\""));
```